# Need to exclude blanks from a Countif formula with a yes/no return

Tags: excel, countif

I'm trying to do a countif to give me a Y or N response if a Y value repeats along the row.

I have this so far and it returns correctly on cells which have data entered in the C:Z cells.

=IF(COUNTIF(C2:Z2,C2)>1,"Y","N")

However, on the rows which don't have the Y value entered in C:Z cells, it's returning a Y response.

I can just delete them as I know that they've not been done yet. But I'd like to have the formula in place for when I do enter the cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is counting the number of instances in C2:Z2 that are equal to C2.  So this will always equal at least 1.  If C2 in "no" and another cell is also "no" your countif function will return 2 and your if statement will return "Y".

It sounds like you want the formula to be comparing to the value "Y" and not to cell C2.  If this is the case then try.

> =IF(COUNTIF(C2:Z2,"Y")>1,"Y","N")

If not you will need to post a clearer example of what your data looks like to return both a positive and negative response.